# Fourier transform Excercise

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am stuck on an excerise which says that prove the fourier transform $f(k)$ of a real function satisfied the condition $f(-k)=f*(-k)$. Where the astericks denotes the complex congugate.

I am beginning to think there is a typo as I am getting it to be $f(-k)=f*(k)$.

By def

$$f(k)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-ikx}dx$$
LHS 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)(\cos kx+i\sin kx)dx$$

RHS 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e*^{ikx}dx$$
$$..$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)(\cos kx-i\sin kx)dx$$
Sorry I dont have latex installed, Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Most likely a typo, why? would you write $f(-k) = f^*(-k)$ instead of $f(k) = f^*(k)$.

Comment: Maybe the exercise has a typo? IMO f(-k) = f*(k) is right.

Comment: I am not sure what is meant by your question other than that is the way the question was phrased

Comment: You don't need to have latex installed. Please have a look at this site and try to edit your question so that other people can read it ;) (http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definition of Fourier transform:
\begin{align*}
\tilde{f}(k) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ikx} f(x) dx \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \cos kx dx - i \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \sin kx dx \\
\Rightarrow \tilde{f}^*(k) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \cos kx dx + i \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \sin kx dx \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ikx} f(x) dx \\
&= \tilde{f}(-k)
\end{align*}

So it seems that $\tilde{f}(-k) = \tilde{f}^*(k)$.

$\tilde{f}(-k) = \tilde{f}^*(-k)$ can't be true because it would imply that $\tilde{f}$ is always real.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, so would that imply the only way this can be satisfied is if say f(-k) =a where a is real and then the proof would hold?